# When printing a page while not being logged in some of the answers' text is hidden

Tags: bug, status-declined, unregistered-users, printing

I printed [What does C++ do better than D?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97207/what-does-c-do-better-than-d) while I was not logged in, and the following banner was printed on each page **over** the answers, thus hiding part of the text of whichever answer was on a page break.

> Welcome to Q&A for expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development — check out the FAQ!

The banner should either not be printed at all, or printed inline and not hovering over the text.

Answer (score 2):

Simply click the [x] on the alert, since it is one time and stored with cookies. Then none of your printing will contain the banner.

Alternately, use Stack Printer:

[StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite)

Comment: Unregistered users are not likely to go to StackPrinter or know about clicking the `[x]` so I don't think this is a viable workaround.

Comment: so users don't know how to close windows in their OS, either? That seems .. unlikely.

Comment: I'm saying that an unregistered user can't be expected to be familiar with the site and seeing the banner at the top of the page does not convey the fact that it will obstruct the answers. After printing a page out an unregistered user will understand that the banner should be closed but it's too late.

Comment: Simply not displaying it in the print view seems to be enough.